# Calling __enter__ and __exit__ manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I've googled [`calling __enter__ manually`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=python%20calling%20__enter__()%20manually) but with no luck. So let's imagine I have *MySQL* connector class that uses `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions (originally used with `with` statement) to connect/disconnect from a database.

And let's have a class that uses 2 of these connections (for example for data sync). *Note: this is not my real-life scenario, but it seems to be the simplest example*.

Easiest way to make it all work together is class like this:

```
class DataSync(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.master_connection = MySQLConnection(param_set_1)
        self.slave_connection = MySQLConnection(param_set_2)

    def __enter__(self):
            self.master_connection.__enter__()
            self.slave_connection.__enter__()
            return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, traceback):
            self.master_connection.__exit__(exc_type, exc, traceback)
            self.slave_connection.__exit__(exc_type, exc, traceback)

    # Some real operation functions

# Simple usage example
with DataSync() as sync:
    records = sync.master_connection.fetch_records()
    sync.slave_connection.push_records(records)
```

**Q**: Is it okay (is there anything wrong) to call `__enter__`/`__exit__` manually like this?

Pylint 1.1.0 didn't issue any warnings on this, nor have I found any article about it (google link in the beggining).

And what about calling:

```
try:
    # Db query
except MySQL.ServerDisconnectedException:
    self.master_connection.__exit__(None, None, None)
    self.master_connection.__enter__()
    # Retry
```

Is this a good/bad practice? Why?

Comment: I'd say its fine, see as [we are all consenting adults here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html), or you could use something like [ExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), which will do the calling for you.

Comment: The \_\_exit\_\_ method will be called in the with statement at any rate, not so when calling those methods manually, afaik.

Comment: @XORcist I've added sample usage example... In provided case (I believe) you have to call it manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note: This answer doesn't properly account for possible failures when there are multiple calls to underlying `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. See Eric's answer for one that does deal with that.**

No, there's nothing wrong with that. There are even places in the standard library that do it. Like the [`multiprocessing` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/767fd62b59a9/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#l95):

```
class SemLock(object):

    def __init__(self, kind, value, maxvalue, *, ctx):
            ...
            try:
                sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
                    kind, value, maxvalue, self._make_name(),
                    unlink_now)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
    ...

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._semlock.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return self._semlock.__exit__(*args)
```

Or the [`tempfile` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/767fd62b59a9/Lib/tempfile.py#l410):

```
class _TemporaryFileWrapper:

    def __init__(self, file, name, delete=True):
        self.file = file
        self.name = name
        self.delete = delete
        self._closer = _TemporaryFileCloser(file, name, delete)

    ...

    # The underlying __enter__ method returns the wrong object
    # (self.file) so override it to return the wrapper
    def __enter__(self):
        self.file.__enter__()
        return self

    # Need to trap __exit__ as well to ensure the file gets
    # deleted when used in a with statement
    def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
        result = self.file.__exit__(exc, value, tb)
        self.close()
        return result
```

The standard library examples aren't calling `__enter__`/`__exit__` for two objects, but if you've got an object that's responsible for creating/destroying the context for multiple objects instead of just one, calling `__enter__`/`__exit__` for all of them is fine.

The only potential gotcha is properly handling the return values of the `__enter__` `__exit__` calls for the objects you're managing. With `__enter__`, you need to make sure you're returning whatever `state` is required for the user of your wrapper object to get back from the `with ... as <state>:` call. With `__exit__`, you need to decide if you want to propagate any exception that occurred inside the context (by returning `False`), or suppress it (by returning `True`). Your managed objects could try to do it either way, you need to decide what makes sense for the wrapper object.

Comment: "if you've got an object that's responsible for creating/destroying the context for multiple objects instead of just one, calling `__enter__`/`__exit__` for all of them is fine" - no, it's not, at least not without managing possible failures along the way.

Answer (score 25):

Your first example is not a good idea:

1. What happens if `slave_connection.__enter__` throws an exception:

   - `master_connection` acquires its resource
   - `slave_connection` fails
   - `DataSync.__enter__` propogates the exception
   - `DataSync.__exit__` does not run
   - `master_connection` is never cleaned up!
   - Potential for Bad Things
2. What happens if `master_connection.__exit__` throws an exception?

   - `DataSync.__exit__` finished early
   - `slave_connection` is never cleaned up!
   - Potential for Bad Things

---

`contextlib.ExitStack` can help here:

```
def __enter__(self):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        stack.enter_context(self.master_connection)
        stack.enter_context(self.slave_connection)
        self._stack = stack.pop_all()
    return self

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, traceback):
    self._stack.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc, traceback)
```

Asking the same questions:

1. What happens if `slave_connection.__enter__` throws an exception:

   - The with block is exited, and `stack` cleans up `master_connection`
   - Everything is ok!
2. What happens if `master_connection.__exit__` throws an exception?

   - Doesn't matter, `slave_connection` gets cleaned up before this is called
   - Everything is ok!
3. Ok, what happens if `slave_connection.__exit__` throws an exception?

   - `ExitStack` makes sure to call `master_connection.__exit__` whatever happens to the slave connection
   - Everything is ok!

---

There's nothing wrong with calling `__enter__` directly, but if you need to call it on more than one object, make sure you clean up properly!

Comment: I failed to mention that I ran Python 3.2 at the time and according to [`contextlib.ExitStack` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) it was added in `3.3`, so at the time dano's most accurate, but I agree that for 3.3+ this is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: @Vyktor: There's always the [`contextlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contextlib2) backport for earlier versions! Even before ExitStack, you could have achieved safety with some careful try/finallys

Comment: @Eric what's your opinion on combining it with the flask hooks `before_request` and `after_request`? For example calling `__enter__` inside `before_request` and `__exit__` in `after_request`?

Comment: @exhuma: `teardown_request` looks more appropriate than `after_request`

Answer (score 11):

I answer to the header only, i.e. to call `__enter__` and `__exit__` e.g. from an IPython prompt. You can do it this way:

```py
ctx.__enter__()
ctx.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
```