# How can I preview streaming images in tkinter with Allied Vision camera that uses Vimba SDK?

Tags: python, tkinter, video, camera, alliedvision

I want to display images from an Allied Vision camera inside a tkinter frame using OpenCV and the SDK for the camera, [VimbaPython](https://github.com/alliedvision/VimbaPython).

The only possible way to initialize the camera is with a Python `with` statement:

```
with Vimba.get_instance() as vimba:
    cams = vimba.get_all_cameras()
    with cams[0] as camera:
        camera.get_frame()
        # Convert frame to opencv image, then use Image.fromarray and ImageTk.PhotoImage to
        # display it on the tkinter GUI
```

Everything works fine so far. But I don't only need a single frame. Instead, I need to continuously get frames and display them on the screen so that it is streaming.
I found that one way to do it is to call the `.after(delay, function)` method from a tkinter Label widget.
So, after obtaining one frame, I want to call the same function to get a new frame and display it again. The code would look like that:

```
with Vimba.get_instance() as vimba:
    cams = vimba.get_all_cameras()
    with cams[0] as camera:

        def show_frame():
            frame = camera.get_frame()
            frame = frame.as_opencv_image()
            im = Image.fromarray(frame)
            img = Image.PhotoImage(im)
            lblVideo.configure(image=img)   # this is the Tkinter Label Widget
            lblVideo.image = img

        show_frame()
        lblVideo.after(20, show_frame)
```

Then this shows the first frame and stops, throwing an error saying that Vimba needs to be initialized with a `with` statement. I don't know much about Python, but it looks like when I call the function with the `.after()` method it ends the with statement.

I would like to know if it is possible to execute this `show_frame()` function without ending the `with`. Also, I can't initialize the camera every time because the program goes really slow.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use thread to run the capture code and pass the frames read via `queue`.  Then the main `tkinter` application reads the `queue` and show the frames periodically using `.after()`.

Below is an example based on your posted code:

```py
import threading
from queue import SimpleQueue
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from vimba import Vimba

def camera_streaming(queue):
    global is_streaming
    is_streaming = True
    print("streaming started")
    with Vimba.get_instance() as vimba:
        with vimba.get_all_cameras()[0] as camera:
            while is_streaming:
                frame = camera.get_frame()
                frame = frame.as_opencv_image()
                im = Image.fromarray(frame)
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
                queue.put(img) # put the capture image into queue
    print("streaming stopped")

def start_streaming():
    start_btn["state"] = "disabled" # disable start button to avoid running the threaded task more than once
    stop_btn["state"] = "normal"    # enable stop button to allow user to stop the threaded task
    show_streaming()
    threading.Thread(target=camera_streaming, args=(queue,), daemon=True).start()

def stop_streaming():
    global is_streaming, after_id
    is_streaming = False  # terminate the streaming thread
    if after_id:
        lblVideo.after_cancel(after_id) # cancel the showing task
        after_id = None
    stop_btn["state"] = "disabled" # disable stop button
    start_btn["state"] = "normal"  # enable start button

# periodical task to show frames in queue
def show_streaming():
    global after_id
    if not queue.empty():
        image = queue.get()
        lblVideo.config(image=image)
        lblVideo.image = image
    after_id = lblVideo.after(20, show_streaming)

queue = SimpleQueue() # queue for video frames
after_id = None

root = tk.Tk()

lblVideo = tk.Label(root, image=tk.PhotoImage(), width=640, height=480)
lblVideo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

start_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Start", width=10, command=start_streaming)
start_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

stop_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=10, command=stop_streaming, state="disabled")
stop_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I don't have the camera and the SDK installed, the above code may not work for you.  I just demonstrate how to use thread, queue and `.after()`.

Below is a testing `vimba` module (saved as `vimba.py`) I use to simulate `VimbaPython` module using `OpenCV` and a webcam:

```py
import cv2

class Frame:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame

    def as_opencv_image(self):
        return self.frame

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, cam_id=0):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_id, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.cap.release()
        return self

    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            return Frame(frame)

class Vimba:
    _instance = None
    
    @classmethod
    def get_instance(self):
        if self._instance is None:
            self._instance = Vimba()
        return self._instance

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return self

    def get_all_cameras(self):
        return (Camera(),)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but I ran into a similar problem with the Allied Vision cameras and found the solution to be relatively robust. So I hope this helps someone, even if not the OP.

An alternative to using with statements is using `__enter__` and `__exit__` (see sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635684/calling-enter-and-exit-manually)). With this, I created a class for the Vimba camera and during the `__init__` I used these functions twice: once to initialize the Vimba instance, and once to open the camera itself. An example as follows...

`vimba_handle = Vimba.get_instance().__enter__()`

`camera = vimba_handle.get_all_cameras()[0].__enter__()`

I'll include a longer snippet as code as well, but please note my purpose was slightly different the OP's intent. Hopefully, it is still useful.

```
class VimbaCam:

    def __init__(self, device_id=0):
        # Variables
        self.current_frame = np.array([])
        self.device = None
        self.device_id = device_id
        self.vimba_handle = Vimba.get_instance().__enter__()
        self.is_streaming = False
        self.scale_window = 4
        self.stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_stream, daemon=True)

        # Default settings
        self.auto_exposure = "Off"
        self.auto_gain = "Off"
        self.acquisition = "Continuous"
        self.exposure_us = 200000
        self.fps = 6.763
        self.gain = 0
        self.gamma = 1

        self.open()

    def close(self):
        if self.device is not None:
            if self.is_streaming:
                self.stop_stream()
                time.sleep(1)
            self.device.__exit__(None, None, None)
            self.vimba_handle.__exit__(None, None, None)

    def open(self):
        cams = self.vimba_handle.get_all_cameras()
        if not cams:
            error_check(151, currentframe())
        else:
            self.device = cams[self.device_id].__enter__()

        self.set_defaults()
        self.start_stream()

    def start_stream(self):
        if self.device is not None:
            self.is_streaming = True
            self.stream_thread.start()
            time.sleep(1)

    def thread_stream(self):
        while self.is_streaming:
            current_frame = self.device.get_frame().as_opencv_image()
            h, w, _ = current_frame.shape
            self.current_frame = current_frame.reshape((h, w))
        self.stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_stream, daemon=True)

    def stop_stream(self):
        if self.device is not None:
            self.is_streaming = False

    def live_video(self):
        if self.device is not None:
            window_name = "Allied Vision"
            h, w = self.current_frame.shape
            w = int(w / self.scale_window)
            h = int(h / self.scale_window)
            cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, w, h)
            while 1:
                cv2.imshow(window_name, self.current_frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
                if cv2.getWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
                    break
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def set_defaults(self):
        if self.device is not None:
            # Exposure time settings
            self.device.ExposureAuto.set(self.auto_exposure)
            self.device.ExposureTimeAbs.set(self.exposure_us)

            # Gain settings
            self.device.GainAuto.set(self.auto_gain)
            self.device.Gain.set(self.gain)

            # Gamma settings
            self.device.Gamma.set(self.gamma)
            self.device.AcquisitionMode.set(self.acquisition)
            self.device.AcquisitionFrameRateAbs.set(self.fps)

            # Try to adjust GeV packet size (available for GigE only)
            try:
                self.device.GVSPAdjustPacketSize.run()
                while not self.device.GVSPAdjustPacketSize.is_done():
                    pass
            except (AttributeError, VimbaFeatureError):
                pass

            # Color formatting (tries mono first, then color)
            cv_formats = intersect_pixel_formats(self.device.get_pixel_formats(), OPENCV_PIXEL_FORMATS)
            mono_formats = intersect_pixel_formats(cv_formats, MONO_PIXEL_FORMATS)
            color_formats = intersect_pixel_formats(cv_formats, COLOR_PIXEL_FORMATS)
            if mono_formats:
                self.device.set_pixel_format(mono_formats[0])
            elif color_formats:
                self.device.set_pixel_format(color_formats[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    dev = VimbaCam()
    dev.live_video()
    dev.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to read the frames in openCV and display them in tkinter label. I was able to do so using the below code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

video_path = "SAMPLE/STORED_VIDEO/PATH"

root = tk.Tk()
base_img = Image.open("PATH/TO/DEFAULT/LABLE/IMAGE")
img_obj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(base_img)
lblVideo = tk.Label(root, image=img_obj)
lblVideo.pack()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

if cap.isOpened():
    def show_frame():
        _, frame = cap.read()
        im = Image.fromarray(frame)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        lblVideo.configure(image=img)
        lblVideo.image = img
        lblVideo.after(1, show_frame)  # Need to create callback here   
    show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

Although this doesnot contain the with statement, you can try replacing the `after()` callback inside the `show_frame` function itself.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the problem is that the camera that I use cannot be initialized with openCV VideoCapture, that's why I have to do it with that with statement

Comment: Thanks. Also your query got resolved. That matters.